# Why does the debugger always skip one line in this program?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I am writing a template class of a matrix named `Matrix`, and I rewrite the default constructor like this:

```
template<typename _Tp, size_t m, size_t n> inline
Matrix<_Tp, m, n>::Matrix()
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i != m*n; ++i) val[i] = _Tp(0);
}
```

And in my test file I write this:

```
SC::Matrix<double, 3, 3> Mat();
```

All these are good when I build the program. But I always get wrong result when I run the test program.

And When I try to find reasons I find that the debugger always skip over definition of `Mat`; At the first I think that it may because I modified the files after I build this program, so I delete all the build results(automatically generated by cmake) and rebuild it. But it's useless, the problem is still there.

Is there anyone can help me find the reason? Did I provide enough information for this problem?

Comment: Is that a definition of a variable `Mat` that is supposed to be default initialized, or is it a declaration of a function which takes no argument and returns a `SC::Matrix<double, 3, 3>` object?

Comment: When you construct objects on the stack without ctor-params you don't need the `()`: `SC::Matrix<double, 3, 3> Mat;`. Otherwise it may cause your compiler to think of it as a function declaration.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the reason now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say "...the debugger always skip over...", so I assume, you tried to create a variable Mat of type `SC::Matrix<double, 3, 3>` and see how it is default initialized.

If that is true, than

```
SC::Matrix<double, 3, 3> Mat();
```

declares a function called `Mat` taking no args and returning `SC::Matrix<double, 3, 3>`. And of course you can not "debug" a function declaration.
If you want to create a default initialized variable write:

```
SC::Matrix<double, 3, 3> Mat{};
```

or just

```
SC::Matrix<double, 3, 3> Mat;
```

Comment: It is actually function declaration, not definition. You **can** debug a function definition (this is what you mostly debug, actually), but not declaration.

Comment: Thank you, fixed)